# Edges of a bipartite graph $G$ can be painted with $r$ colors $s.t$. at all vertex $v$, the $r$ edges incident with $v$ all have different colors

Tags: combinatorics

Let $r$ be a positive integer. Let $G$ be a bipartite graph such that for every vertex $v$, $deg(v)=r$. Prove that the edges of $G$ can be painted with $r$ colors such that at every vertex $v$, the $r$ edges incident with $v$ all have different colors.

Comment: What are you thoughts sofar? Have you heard of alternating paths. If some vertex $v$ has two incident edges colored with color $i$, then there is some color $j$ which is not incident to $v$. Follow an alternating $i,j$-path and...

Comment: Let (H,K) be a bipartition of the vertices of G.
|H|=|K|.
For every h∈H, let S_h be the set of elements k∈K such that hk is an edge in G.
For every A⊆H, consider ⋃_(a∈A)▒S_a , which is the set of all vertices in K such that there exists b∈K adjacent to at least one vertex a∈A.
Let E_1 be the set of edges incident with some vertex in A and E_2 be the set of edges incident to a vertex v∈K, where v is adjacent to some vertex in A.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Prove it by induction on $r$. The base case $r=1$ is easy. For the induction step use Hall’s marriage theorem to get a matching, remove the edges in the matching, and apply the induction hypothesis to what’s left.